# My Wifi stops working after browsing the web

Tags: wireless, networking, drivers, firefox, network-manager

So I am using Ubuntu 13.10 and I have this USB wifi device (TP-Link TL-WN821N V4) in my computer.

Now when I use internet via terminal, everything is just fine, I can upload and download the whole internet if I want to. But once I open up a browser(does not matter if firefox or chromium), I can navigate to like 4 pages and then my connection stops. I can still see that I am connected but I cannot use the internet anymore.

Also when I disconnect from the currently connected network, I will not be able to reconnect there anymore.

This problem for now is only fixed with a restart. So for every 4 pages I visit, restart.

I have also gotten some logs and info:

Syslog:

```
Apr  7 16:55:11 kaspar-All-Series colord: Using mapping database file /var/lib/colord/mapping.db
Apr  7 16:55:11 kaspar-All-Series colord: Using device database file /var/lib/colord/storage.db
Apr  7 16:55:11 kaspar-All-Series colord: loaded plugin libcd_plugin_scanner.so
Apr  7 16:55:11 kaspar-All-Series colord: plugin /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/colord-plugins/libcd_plugin_sane.so not loaded: plugin refused to load
Apr  7 16:55:11 kaspar-All-Series colord: loaded plugin libcd_plugin_camera.so
Apr  7 16:55:11 kaspar-All-Series colord: Daemon ready for requests
Apr  7 16:55:11 kaspar-All-Series dbus[698]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.ColorManager'
Apr  7 16:55:11 kaspar-All-Series colord: Profile added: icc-b920cdc20756e05653f42f9f171ecec9
Apr  7 16:55:11 kaspar-All-Series colord: Profile added: icc-bbb2b6d0b2f673b7e0b5066a257fc194
Apr  7 16:55:11 kaspar-All-Series colord: Profile added: icc-2aab7bab389c800a5a8cb31a7d6ba1ef
Apr  7 16:55:11 kaspar-All-Series colord: Profile added: icc-7da256bc299fa3e414b0d5bfef41697d
Apr  7 16:55:11 kaspar-All-Series colord: Profile added: icc-10f8fa4e3eae00a31f679de411c9c737
Apr  7 16:55:11 kaspar-All-Series colord: Profile added: icc-0075bbf6787fe025e3e8be7c60ab1cc0
Apr  7 16:55:11 kaspar-All-Series colord: Profile added: icc-ec9cedcd8450615939a12ac24ec5e8dc
Apr  7 16:55:11 kaspar-All-Series colord: Profile added: icc-f719b10f8219a720944043462516a013
Apr  7 16:55:11 kaspar-All-Series kernel: [   20.269308] Adding 8292348k swap on /dev/mapper/cryptswap1.  Priority:-1 extents:1 across:8292348k FS
Apr  7 16:55:11 kaspar-All-Series colord: Profile added: icc-a3fb06a189e5654272f614e56cd57921
Apr  7 16:55:11 kaspar-All-Series colord: Profile added: icc-68e72a11d2fc535f7d3c7d157432bbd1
Apr  7 16:55:11 kaspar-All-Series colord: Profile added: icc-0efe0c4cd9b09c72ff5b0d407ebdbd80
Apr  7 16:55:11 kaspar-All-Series colord: Profile added: icc-c7db4d1010988277db4d076f37757a01
Apr  7 16:55:11 kaspar-All-Series colord: Profile added: icc-93945c373d44de2f7199fc8b0782fadf
Apr  7 16:55:11 kaspar-All-Series colord: Profile added: icc-3ad3ba8e09b76fa91573dc2f1aad6e98
Apr  7 16:55:11 kaspar-All-Series colord: Profile added: icc-0fb902a132159af7eee4a70af0921c06
Apr  7 16:55:11 kaspar-All-Series colord: Profile added: icc-f3f81cb5b41e8de556fdcc01ccb29c5f
Apr  7 16:55:11 kaspar-All-Series colord: Profile added: icc-9d21c156e7631af5bc00bec7b35c31a9
Apr  7 16:55:11 kaspar-All-Series colord: Profile added: icc-bab0d408ed0547d599c49f07675cdffc
Apr  7 16:55:11 kaspar-All-Series colord: Profile added: icc-e209f6f1e897d6fbc3bbc66e21fe46a9
Apr  7 16:55:11 kaspar-All-Series colord: Profile added: icc-3660934ca71cad605724215aa7e6a5a4
Apr  7 16:55:11 kaspar-All-Series colord: Profile added: icc-a5cf2e0debcd2aed283c58d15ca28da9
Apr  7 16:55:11 kaspar-All-Series colord: Profile added: icc-465d1507ae264c466248b7efc1f2ee22
Apr  7 16:55:11 kaspar-All-Series colord: Profile added: icc-33eef553a4017f238711fb8afc0d6e87
Apr  7 16:55:11 kaspar-All-Series colord: Profile added: icc-66cedf35b4ba8c0be05be4e53ee68bbe
Apr  7 16:55:11 kaspar-All-Series colord: Device added: xrandr-BenQ-BenQ xl2411t-8CD00558SL0
Apr  7 16:55:11 kaspar-All-Series colord: Automatic metadata add icc-68c96ce83f512dee5e392b42240c6483 to xrandr-BenQ-BenQ xl2411t-8CD00558SL0
Apr  7 16:55:11 kaspar-All-Series colord: Profile added: icc-68c96ce83f512dee5e392b42240c6483
Apr  7 16:55:11 kaspar-All-Series whoopsie[1018]: online
Apr  7 16:55:11 kaspar-All-Series dbus[698]: [system] Activating service name='org.freedesktop.RealtimeKit1' (using servicehelper)
Apr  7 16:55:11 kaspar-All-Series dbus[698]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.RealtimeKit1'
Apr  7 16:55:11 kaspar-All-Series rtkit-daemon[1676]: Successfully called chroot.
Apr  7 16:55:11 kaspar-All-Series rtkit-daemon[1676]: Successfully dropped privileges.
Apr  7 16:55:11 kaspar-All-Series rtkit-daemon[1676]: Successfully limited resources.
Apr  7 16:55:11 kaspar-All-Series rtkit-daemon[1676]: Running.
Apr  7 16:55:11 kaspar-All-Series rtkit-daemon[1676]: Canary thread running.
Apr  7 16:55:11 kaspar-All-Series rtkit-daemon[1676]: Watchdog thread running.
Apr  7 16:55:11 kaspar-All-Series rtkit-daemon[1676]: Successfully made thread 1674 of process 1674 (n/a) owned by '111' high priority at nice level -11.
Apr  7 16:55:11 kaspar-All-Series rtkit-daemon[1676]: Supervising 1 threads of 1 processes of 1 users.
Apr  7 16:55:12 kaspar-All-Series rtkit-daemon[1676]: Successfully made thread 1726 of process 1674 (n/a) owned by '111' RT at priority 5.
Apr  7 16:55:12 kaspar-All-Series rtkit-daemon[1676]: Supervising 2 threads of 1 processes of 1 users.
Apr  7 16:55:12 kaspar-All-Series rtkit-daemon[1676]: Successfully made thread 1727 of process 1674 (n/a) owned by '111' RT at priority 5.
Apr  7 16:55:12 kaspar-All-Series rtkit-daemon[1676]: Supervising 3 threads of 1 processes of 1 users.
Apr  7 16:55:12 kaspar-All-Series rtkit-daemon[1676]: Successfully made thread 1728 of process 1674 (n/a) owned by '111' RT at priority 5.
Apr  7 16:55:12 kaspar-All-Series rtkit-daemon[1676]: Supervising 4 threads of 1 processes of 1 users.
Apr  7 16:55:12 kaspar-All-Series rtkit-daemon[1676]: Successfully made thread 1730 of process 1730 (n/a) owned by '111' high priority at nice level -11.
Apr  7 16:55:12 kaspar-All-Series rtkit-daemon[1676]: Supervising 5 threads of 2 processes of 1 users.
Apr  7 16:55:12 kaspar-All-Series pulseaudio[1730]: [pulseaudio] pid.c: Daemon already running.
Apr  7 16:55:16 kaspar-All-Series ntpdate[1380]: adjust time server 91.189.89.199 offset 0.009931 sec
Apr  7 16:55:17 kaspar-All-Series lightdm: pam_ecryptfs: Passphrase file wrapped
Apr  7 16:55:17 kaspar-All-Series colord: device removed: xrandr-BenQ-BenQ xl2411t-8CD00558SL0
Apr  7 16:55:17 kaspar-All-Series colord: Profile removed: icc-68c96ce83f512dee5e392b42240c6483
Apr  7 16:55:17 kaspar-All-Series bumblebeed[1775]: No integrated video card found, quitting.
Apr  7 16:55:17 kaspar-All-Series bumblebeed[1790]: No integrated video card found, quitting.
Apr  7 16:55:17 kaspar-All-Series bumblebeed[1804]: No integrated video card found, quitting.
Apr  7 16:55:17 kaspar-All-Series bumblebeed[1813]: No integrated video card found, quitting.
Apr  7 16:55:17 kaspar-All-Series bumblebeed[1823]: No integrated video card found, quitting.
Apr  7 16:55:17 kaspar-All-Series bumblebeed[1833]: No integrated video card found, quitting.
Apr  7 16:55:17 kaspar-All-Series bumblebeed[1843]: No integrated video card found, quitting.
Apr  7 16:55:17 kaspar-All-Series bumblebeed[1852]: No integrated video card found, quitting.
Apr  7 16:55:17 kaspar-All-Series bumblebeed[1862]: No integrated video card found, quitting.
Apr  7 16:55:17 kaspar-All-Series bumblebeed[1871]: No integrated video card found, quitting.
Apr  7 16:55:17 kaspar-All-Series bumblebeed[1880]: No integrated video card found, quitting.
Apr  7 16:55:18 kaspar-All-Series rtkit-daemon[1676]: Successfully made thread 2075 of process 2075 (n/a) owned by '1000' high priority at nice level -11.
Apr  7 16:55:18 kaspar-All-Series rtkit-daemon[1676]: Supervising 5 threads of 2 processes of 2 users.
Apr  7 16:55:19 kaspar-All-Series rtkit-daemon[1676]: Successfully made thread 2211 of process 2075 (n/a) owned by '1000' RT at priority 5.
Apr  7 16:55:19 kaspar-All-Series rtkit-daemon[1676]: Supervising 6 threads of 2 processes of 2 users.
Apr  7 16:55:19 kaspar-All-Series rtkit-daemon[1676]: Successfully made thread 2212 of process 2075 (n/a) owned by '1000' RT at priority 5.
Apr  7 16:55:19 kaspar-All-Series rtkit-daemon[1676]: Supervising 7 threads of 2 processes of 2 users.
Apr  7 16:55:19 kaspar-All-Series rtkit-daemon[1676]: Successfully made thread 2213 of process 2075 (n/a) owned by '1000' RT at priority 5.
Apr  7 16:55:19 kaspar-All-Series rtkit-daemon[1676]: Supervising 8 threads of 2 processes of 2 users.
Apr  7 16:55:19 kaspar-All-Series rtkit-daemon[1676]: Successfully made thread 2215 of process 2215 (n/a) owned by '1000' high priority at nice level -11.
Apr  7 16:55:19 kaspar-All-Series rtkit-daemon[1676]: Supervising 9 threads of 3 processes of 2 users.
Apr  7 16:55:19 kaspar-All-Series pulseaudio[2215]: [pulseaudio] pid.c: Daemon already running.
Apr  7 16:55:19 kaspar-All-Series rtkit-daemon[1676]: Successfully made thread 2218 of process 2218 (n/a) owned by '1000' high priority at nice level -11.
Apr  7 16:55:19 kaspar-All-Series rtkit-daemon[1676]: Supervising 9 threads of 3 processes of 2 users.
Apr  7 16:55:19 kaspar-All-Series pulseaudio[2218]: [pulseaudio] pid.c: Daemon already running.
Apr  7 16:55:19 kaspar-All-Series dbus[698]: [system] Activating service name='org.freedesktop.locale1' (using servicehelper)
Apr  7 16:55:19 kaspar-All-Series dbus[698]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.locale1'
Apr  7 16:55:19 kaspar-All-Series colord: Device added: xrandr-BenQ-BenQ xl2411t-8CD00558SL0
Apr  7 16:55:19 kaspar-All-Series colord: Automatic metadata add icc-fe9ab04f6dcf3546f8a69b3110e4d1c4 to xrandr-BenQ-BenQ xl2411t-8CD00558SL0
Apr  7 16:55:19 kaspar-All-Series colord: Profile added: icc-fe9ab04f6dcf3546f8a69b3110e4d1c4
Apr  7 16:55:19 kaspar-All-Series dbus[698]: [system] Activating service name='org.freedesktop.UDisks2' (using servicehelper)
Apr  7 16:55:19 kaspar-All-Series udisksd[2282]: udisks daemon version 2.1.0 starting
Apr  7 16:55:20 kaspar-All-Series dbus[698]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.UDisks2'
Apr  7 16:55:20 kaspar-All-Series udisksd[2282]: Acquired the name org.freedesktop.UDisks2 on the system message bus
Apr  7 16:55:26 kaspar-All-Series wpa_supplicant[1015]: wlan0: WPA: Group rekeying completed with 00:0e:2e:6e:f4:ca [GTK=CCMP]
Apr  7 16:55:26 kaspar-All-Series whoopsie[1018]: online
Apr  7 16:55:27 kaspar-All-Series whoopsie[1018]: online
Apr  7 16:55:28 kaspar-All-Series NetworkManager[968]: <info> (wlan0): IP6 addrconf timed out or failed.
Apr  7 16:55:28 kaspar-All-Series NetworkManager[968]: <info> Activation (wlan0) Stage 4 of 5 (IPv6 Configure Timeout) scheduled...
Apr  7 16:55:28 kaspar-All-Series NetworkManager[968]: <info> Activation (wlan0) Stage 4 of 5 (IPv6 Configure Timeout) started...
Apr  7 16:55:28 kaspar-All-Series NetworkManager[968]: <info> Activation (wlan0) Stage 4 of 5 (IPv6 Configure Timeout) complete.
Apr  7 16:56:08 kaspar-All-Series whoopsie[1018]: online
Apr  7 16:56:09 kaspar-All-Series whoopsie[1018]: online
Apr  7 16:57:18  whoopsie[1018]: last message repeated 3 times
Apr  7 16:57:26 kaspar-All-Series dbus[698]: [system] Activating service name='org.freedesktop.hostname1' (using servicehelper)
Apr  7 16:57:26 kaspar-All-Series dbus[698]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.hostname1'
Apr  7 16:58:17 kaspar-All-Series whoopsie[1018]: online
Apr  7 16:59:26  whoopsie[1018]: last message repeated 2 times
Apr  7 17:00:36  whoopsie[1018]: last message repeated 2 times
Apr  7 17:02:49 kaspar-All-Series NetworkManager[968]: <info> (wlan0): device state change: activated -> disconnected (reason 'user-requested') [100 30 39]
Apr  7 17:02:49 kaspar-All-Series NetworkManager[968]: <info> (wlan0): deactivating device (reason 'user-requested') [39]
Apr  7 17:02:49 kaspar-All-Series NetworkManager[968]: <info> (wlan0): canceled DHCP transaction, DHCP client pid 1194
Apr  7 17:02:49 kaspar-All-Series avahi-daemon[823]: Withdrawing address record for fe80::a2f3:c1ff:fe1c:a4a8 on wlan0.
Apr  7 17:02:49 kaspar-All-Series avahi-daemon[823]: Leaving mDNS multicast group on interface wlan0.IPv6 with address fe80::a2f3:c1ff:fe1c:a4a8.
Apr  7 17:02:49 kaspar-All-Series avahi-daemon[823]: Interface wlan0.IPv6 no longer relevant for mDNS.
Apr  7 17:02:49 kaspar-All-Series avahi-daemon[823]: Withdrawing address record for 192.168.2.103 on wlan0.
Apr  7 17:02:49 kaspar-All-Series avahi-daemon[823]: Leaving mDNS multicast group on interface wlan0.IPv4 with address 192.168.2.103.
Apr  7 17:02:49 kaspar-All-Series avahi-daemon[823]: Interface wlan0.IPv4 no longer relevant for mDNS.
Apr  7 17:02:49 kaspar-All-Series NetworkManager[968]: <warn> DNS: plugin dnsmasq update failed
Apr  7 17:02:49 kaspar-All-Series NetworkManager[968]: <info> Removing DNS information from /sbin/resolvconf
Apr  7 17:02:49 kaspar-All-Series dnsmasq[1252]: setting upstream servers from DBus
Apr  7 17:02:49 kaspar-All-Series kernel: [  478.926346] wlan0: deauthenticating from 00:0e:2e:6e:f4:ca by local choice (reason=3)
Apr  7 17:02:49 kaspar-All-Series wpa_supplicant[1015]: wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-DISCONNECTED bssid=00:00:00:00:00:00 reason=3
Apr  7 17:02:49 kaspar-All-Series kernel: [  478.928513] cfg80211: Calling CRDA to update world regulatory domain
Apr  7 17:02:49 kaspar-All-Series kernel: [  478.934237] cfg80211: World regulatory domain updated:
Apr  7 17:02:49 kaspar-All-Series kernel: [  478.934245] cfg80211:   (start_freq - end_freq @ bandwidth), (max_antenna_gain, max_eirp)
Apr  7 17:02:49 kaspar-All-Series kernel: [  478.934251] cfg80211:   (2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
Apr  7 17:02:49 kaspar-All-Series kernel: [  478.934255] cfg80211:   (2457000 KHz - 2482000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
Apr  7 17:02:49 kaspar-All-Series kernel: [  478.934258] cfg80211:   (2474000 KHz - 2494000 KHz @ 20000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
Apr  7 17:02:49 kaspar-All-Series kernel: [  478.934261] cfg80211:   (5170000 KHz - 5250000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
Apr  7 17:02:49 kaspar-All-Series kernel: [  478.934264] cfg80211:   (5735000 KHz - 5835000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
Apr  7 17:02:49 kaspar-All-Series whoopsie[1018]: offline
Apr  7 17:02:49 kaspar-All-Series dbus[698]: [system] Activating service name='org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher' (using servicehelper)
Apr  7 17:02:49 kaspar-All-Series NetworkManager[968]: <info> (wlan0): supplicant interface state: completed -> disconnected
Apr  7 17:02:49 kaspar-All-Series dbus[698]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher'
Apr  7 17:02:50 kaspar-All-Series avahi-daemon[823]: Joining mDNS multicast group on interface wlan0.IPv6 with address fe80::a2f3:c1ff:fe1c:a4a8.
Apr  7 17:02:50 kaspar-All-Series avahi-daemon[823]: New relevant interface wlan0.IPv6 for mDNS.
Apr  7 17:02:50 kaspar-All-Series avahi-daemon[823]: Registering new address record for fe80::a2f3:c1ff:fe1c:a4a8 on wlan0.*.
Apr  7 17:02:52 kaspar-All-Series NetworkManager[968]: <info> Activation (wlan0) starting connection 'Seened'
Apr  7 17:02:52 kaspar-All-Series NetworkManager[968]: <info> (wlan0): device state change: disconnected -> prepare (reason 'none') [30 40 0]
Apr  7 17:02:52 kaspar-All-Series NetworkManager[968]: <info> Activation (wlan0) Stage 1 of 5 (Device Prepare) scheduled...
Apr  7 17:02:52 kaspar-All-Series NetworkManager[968]: <info> Activation (wlan0) Stage 1 of 5 (Device Prepare) started...
Apr  7 17:02:52 kaspar-All-Series NetworkManager[968]: <info> Activation (wlan0) Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) scheduled...
Apr  7 17:02:52 kaspar-All-Series NetworkManager[968]: <info> Activation (wlan0) Stage 1 of 5 (Device Prepare) complete.
Apr  7 17:02:52 kaspar-All-Series NetworkManager[968]: <info> Activation (wlan0) Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) starting...
Apr  7 17:02:52 kaspar-All-Series NetworkManager[968]: <info> (wlan0): device state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none') [40 50 0]
Apr  7 17:02:52 kaspar-All-Series NetworkManager[968]: <info> Activation (wlan0/wireless): access point 'Seened' has security, but secrets are required.
Apr  7 17:02:52 kaspar-All-Series NetworkManager[968]: <info> (wlan0): device state change: config -> need-auth (reason 'none') [50 60 0]
Apr  7 17:02:52 kaspar-All-Series NetworkManager[968]: <info> Activation (wlan0) Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) complete.
Apr  7 17:02:52 kaspar-All-Series whoopsie[1018]: offline
Apr  7 17:02:52 kaspar-All-Series NetworkManager[968]: <info> Activation (wlan0) Stage 1 of 5 (Device Prepare) scheduled...
Apr  7 17:02:52 kaspar-All-Series NetworkManager[968]: <info> Activation (wlan0) Stage 1 of 5 (Device Prepare) started...
Apr  7 17:02:52 kaspar-All-Series NetworkManager[968]: <info> (wlan0): device state change: need-auth -> prepare (reason 'none') [60 40 0]
Apr  7 17:02:52 kaspar-All-Series NetworkManager[968]: <info> Activation (wlan0) Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) scheduled...
Apr  7 17:02:52 kaspar-All-Series NetworkManager[968]: <info> Activation (wlan0) Stage 1 of 5 (Device Prepare) complete.
Apr  7 17:02:52 kaspar-All-Series NetworkManager[968]: <info> Activation (wlan0) Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) starting...
Apr  7 17:02:52 kaspar-All-Series NetworkManager[968]: <info> (wlan0): device state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none') [40 50 0]
Apr  7 17:02:52 kaspar-All-Series NetworkManager[968]: <info> Activation (wlan0/wireless): connection 'Seened' has security, and secrets exist.  No new secrets needed.
Apr  7 17:02:52 kaspar-All-Series NetworkManager[968]: <info> Config: added 'ssid' value 'Seened'
Apr  7 17:02:52 kaspar-All-Series NetworkManager[968]: <info> Config: added 'scan_ssid' value '1'
Apr  7 17:02:52 kaspar-All-Series NetworkManager[968]: <info> Config: added 'key_mgmt' value 'WPA-PSK'
Apr  7 17:02:52 kaspar-All-Series NetworkManager[968]: <info> Config: added 'auth_alg' value 'OPEN'
Apr  7 17:02:52 kaspar-All-Series NetworkManager[968]: <info> Config: added 'psk' value '<omitted>'
Apr  7 17:02:52 kaspar-All-Series NetworkManager[968]: <info> Activation (wlan0) Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) complete.
Apr  7 17:02:52 kaspar-All-Series NetworkManager[968]: <info> Config: set interface ap_scan to 1
Apr  7 17:02:52 kaspar-All-Series NetworkManager[968]: <info> (wlan0): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> scanning
Apr  7 17:02:52 kaspar-All-Series wpa_supplicant[1015]: wlan0: SME: Trying to authenticate with 00:0e:2e:6e:f4:ca (SSID='Seened' freq=2462 MHz)
Apr  7 17:02:52 kaspar-All-Series kernel: [  482.307255] wlan0: authenticate with 00:0e:2e:6e:f4:ca
Apr  7 17:02:52 kaspar-All-Series kernel: [  482.308277] wlan0: send auth to 00:0e:2e:6e:f4:ca (try 1/3)
Apr  7 17:02:52 kaspar-All-Series NetworkManager[968]: <info> (wlan0): supplicant interface state: scanning -> authenticating
Apr  7 17:02:53 kaspar-All-Series kernel: [  483.167399] wlan0: send auth to 00:0e:2e:6e:f4:ca (try 2/3)
Apr  7 17:02:54 kaspar-All-Series kernel: [  484.192226] wlan0: send auth to 00:0e:2e:6e:f4:ca (try 3/3)
Apr  7 17:02:55 kaspar-All-Series kernel: [  485.169011] wlan0: authentication with 00:0e:2e:6e:f4:ca timed out
Apr  7 17:02:55 kaspar-All-Series NetworkManager[968]: <info> (wlan0): supplicant interface state: authenticating -> disconnected
Apr  7 17:02:55 kaspar-All-Series NetworkManager[968]: <info> (wlan0): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> scanning
Apr  7 17:02:56 kaspar-All-Series wpa_supplicant[1015]: wlan0: SME: Trying to authenticate with 00:0e:2e:6e:f4:ca (SSID='Seened' freq=2462 MHz)
Apr  7 17:02:56 kaspar-All-Series kernel: [  485.982272] wlan0: authenticate with 00:0e:2e:6e:f4:ca
Apr  7 17:02:56 kaspar-All-Series kernel: [  485.982786] wlan0: direct probe to 00:0e:2e:6e:f4:ca (try 1/3)
Apr  7 17:02:56 kaspar-All-Series NetworkManager[968]: <info> (wlan0): supplicant interface state: scanning -> authenticating
Apr  7 17:02:56 kaspar-All-Series kernel: [  486.185834] wlan0: direct probe to 00:0e:2e:6e:f4:ca (try 2/3)
Apr  7 17:02:56 kaspar-All-Series kernel: [  486.389998] wlan0: direct probe to 00:0e:2e:6e:f4:ca (try 3/3)
Apr  7 17:02:57 kaspar-All-Series kernel: [  486.594162] wlan0: authentication with 00:0e:2e:6e:f4:ca timed out
Apr  7 17:02:57 kaspar-All-Series NetworkManager[968]: <info> (wlan0): supplicant interface state: authenticating -> disconnected
Apr  7 17:02:57 kaspar-All-Series NetworkManager[968]: <info> (wlan0): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> scanning
Apr  7 17:02:57 kaspar-All-Series wpa_supplicant[1015]: wlan0: SME: Trying to authenticate with 00:0e:2e:6e:f4:ca (SSID='Seened' freq=2462 MHz)
Apr  7 17:02:57 kaspar-All-Series kernel: [  487.411433] wlan0: authenticate with 00:0e:2e:6e:f4:ca
Apr  7 17:02:57 kaspar-All-Series kernel: [  487.412028] wlan0: direct probe to 00:0e:2e:6e:f4:ca (try 1/3)
Apr  7 17:02:57 kaspar-All-Series NetworkManager[968]: <info> (wlan0): supplicant interface state: scanning -> authenticating
Apr  7 17:02:58 kaspar-All-Series kernel: [  487.614987] wlan0: direct probe to 00:0e:2e:6e:f4:ca (try 2/3)
Apr  7 17:02:58 kaspar-All-Series kernel: [  487.819151] wlan0: direct probe to 00:0e:2e:6e:f4:ca (try 3/3)
Apr  7 17:02:58 kaspar-All-Series kernel: [  488.023313] wlan0: authentication with 00:0e:2e:6e:f4:ca timed out
Apr  7 17:02:58 kaspar-All-Series NetworkManager[968]: <info> (wlan0): supplicant interface state: authenticating -> disconnected
Apr  7 17:02:58 kaspar-All-Series NetworkManager[968]: <info> (wlan0): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> scanning
Apr  7 17:02:59 kaspar-All-Series wpa_supplicant[1015]: wlan0: SME: Trying to authenticate with 00:0e:2e:6e:f4:ca (SSID='Seened' freq=2462 MHz)
Apr  7 17:02:59 kaspar-All-Series kernel: [  488.836605] wlan0: authenticate with 00:0e:2e:6e:f4:ca
Apr  7 17:02:59 kaspar-All-Series kernel: [  488.837098] wlan0: direct probe to 00:0e:2e:6e:f4:ca (try 1/3)
Apr  7 17:02:59 kaspar-All-Series NetworkManager[968]: <info> (wlan0): supplicant interface state: scanning -> authenticating
Apr  7 17:02:59 kaspar-All-Series kernel: [  489.040139] wlan0: direct probe to 00:0e:2e:6e:f4:ca (try 2/3)
Apr  7 17:02:59 kaspar-All-Series kernel: [  489.244301] wlan0: direct probe to 00:0e:2e:6e:f4:ca (try 3/3)
Apr  7 17:03:00 kaspar-All-Series kernel: [  489.448470] wlan0: authentication with 00:0e:2e:6e:f4:ca timed out
Apr  7 17:03:00 kaspar-All-Series NetworkManager[968]: <info> (wlan0): supplicant interface state: authenticating -> disconnected
Apr  7 17:03:00 kaspar-All-Series NetworkManager[968]: <info> (wlan0): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> scanning
Apr  7 17:03:00 kaspar-All-Series wpa_supplicant[1015]: wlan0: SME: Trying to authenticate with 00:0e:2e:6e:f4:ca (SSID='Seened' freq=2462 MHz)
Apr  7 17:03:00 kaspar-All-Series kernel: [  490.269716] wlan0: authenticate with 00:0e:2e:6e:f4:ca
Apr  7 17:03:00 kaspar-All-Series kernel: [  490.270177] wlan0: direct probe to 00:0e:2e:6e:f4:ca (try 1/3)
Apr  7 17:03:00 kaspar-All-Series NetworkManager[968]: <info> (wlan0): supplicant interface state: scanning -> authenticating
Apr  7 17:03:01 kaspar-All-Series kernel: [  490.473263] wlan0: direct probe to 00:0e:2e:6e:f4:ca (try 2/3)
Apr  7 17:03:01 kaspar-All-Series kernel: [  490.677427] wlan0: direct probe to 00:0e:2e:6e:f4:ca (try 3/3)
Apr  7 17:03:01 kaspar-All-Series kernel: [  490.881596] wlan0: authentication with 00:0e:2e:6e:f4:ca timed out
Apr  7 17:03:01 kaspar-All-Series NetworkManager[968]: <info> (wlan0): supplicant interface state: authenticating -> disconnected
Apr  7 17:03:01 kaspar-All-Series NetworkManager[968]: <info> (wlan0): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> scanning
Apr  7 17:03:04 kaspar-All-Series NetworkManager[968]: <info> (wlan0): device state change: config -> disconnected (reason 'user-requested') [50 30 39]
Apr  7 17:03:04 kaspar-All-Series NetworkManager[968]: <info> (wlan0): deactivating device (reason 'user-requested') [39]
Apr  7 17:03:04 kaspar-All-Series NetworkManager[968]: <info> (wlan0): supplicant interface state: scanning -> disconnected
Apr  7 17:03:04 kaspar-All-Series whoopsie[1018]: offline
```

And this is output from nm-tool:

```
NetworkManager Tool

State: disconnected

- Device: eth0 -----------------------------------------------------------------
  Type:              Wired
  Driver:            r8169
  State:             unavailable
  Default:           no
  HW Address:        74:D0:2B:9D:81:7F

  Capabilities:
    Carrier Detect:  yes

  Wired Properties
    Carrier:         off


- Device: wlan0 ----------------------------------------------------------------
  Type:              802.11 WiFi
  Driver:            rtl8192cu
  State:             disconnected
  Default:           no
  HW Address:        A0:F3:C1:1C:A4:A8

  Capabilities:

  Wireless Properties
    WEP Encryption:  yes
    WPA Encryption:  yes
    WPA2 Encryption: yes

  Wireless Access Points 
    Seened:          Infra, 00:0E:2E:6E:F4:CA, Freq 2462 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 83 WPA2
```

Maybe worth to mention that I have also tried to install the windows drivers with windows drivers installer program that Linux has, but that resulted with horrible effects. I had to reinstall Ubuntu after that.

So yes, what could be a problem here? Am I using the wrong open-source driver here? And do you guys need anymore info. I hope I took the syslog info from the right spots, from the time table it does seem like the time the network anomaly occurred.

Comment: Is there any more info needed? I would gladly supply any.

Answer (score 0):

Found a reference to [this bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-backports-modules-2.6.32/+bug/495562) in which comments suggests blacklisting the driver like this:

```
echo "blacklist ar9170usb" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-ar9170.conf
```

After reboot, it should work better. If not, remove the `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-ar9170.conf` file.

Comment: Okay, so I tried it and I was able to browse for a little bit longer this time and also the pages loaded faster in my opinion, but the connection stopped after some time again. I removed the blacklist file now. How should I proceed now?

Comment: Also, I noticed now that when this wifi problem happens and I go to Wifi options, then I can untick the Enable Wifi button and then re-enable it. This will get me the connection back without a restart now. But it is still pretty ridiculous ofcourse to do this after loading 4 pages  every time.

Comment: Any leads on this?